# listview using alternate row layout files?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview

I am trying to design instruction page for my App.

My Instruction layout page would be like a textview describing how to use certain feature of the App followed below by Imageview depicting how to use it in the App.

Now there would be like 12 to 13 such rows where there would combination of textview followed by Imageview below.

So my question is  how should i go about implementing this in **listview** **OR** should i go with **Scrollview** and just go adding such 12 imageviews below textviews combination inside linearlayout??

Comment: you must create custom listview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a Custom listview. Inflate a custom layout for each row in listview. Set the custom adapter to listview.

Custom layout with image and text.

Implement a custom adapter overide getView

row.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Then in custom adapter's getVIew

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { 
          ViewHolder holder; 

             if (convertView == null) { 
                 convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, 
                         parent, false);
                 holder = new ViewHolder(); 
                 holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1); 
                 holder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                convertView.setTag(holder); 
            } else { 
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag(); 
            } 
            holder.textView.setText("Position at"+position);
                    // set image to imageview
            return convertView; 
    }
```

For sample you can check this blog

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/